# PHP: Generate implementations out of interfaces in IntelliJ

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I was wondering if there is no quick solution for creating a new class(implementation) out of an interface. 
Usually i define my interface php file and then want to implement it without creating a class manually. 
I found from different sources, that (on mac) option+enter while having the cursor on the interface name in the file will do the trick as there will show up an "Implement interface..." hint. But on my mac, it doesn't.

Could it be, that this feature isn't available for IntelliJ Ultimate + php plugin but for PhpStorm?

I thought until here that you have similar function in IntelliJ with php extension ...

Best regards

Comment: It should be available there, just checked on IJ IDEA + PHP plugin. The action is available via "Show Intention Actions" action.

Comment: Where did you found this menu point? If i set the courser exactly over the interface name in the file itself, no bulb shows up ... even option+enter will show nothing

Comment: that's weird. See how it should work in IJ IDEA + PHP: https://i.gyazo.com/21eda2eb1cf6f7719cd2aa1e6d748fd2.mp4. Not sure here... Try disabling all custom plugins, then enable PHP plugin back & try again. Btw, is it a pure PHP file? Are php-related features (e.g. completion) work there?

Comment: Hey @Ástþór ... unfortunately i had an old IntelliJ Version (2018.2 or something like this), where this feature maybe wasn't present. Now with a 2019 Version it works. That was a bit curious to me to have such a basic feature in IntelliJ for less than one year ... Thanks anyway!

Comment: glad this is now working :)